# A Letter and Puzzle From Grandma

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, story

---

[ EDIT: It's OK to skip the long, boring letter for now, and go straight to Stage 1 of the puzzle.]

Dear Grandson,

I could use a break, so I came to your grandpa's farm to unwind. However, woe to me! Animal sounds here seem to never stop- a dove coo, a cow moo, a goat maa, a crow caw, a wee kitten mew, auk cries, a yak grunt, ayu splashing, emu drumming.... I even wanted to sic Milo on those emus! Speaking of that goat- he always looks sus, as if he plans to break into my veggie garden. Even apart from animal noises, last night we were jolted awake by thunder. I made an eek sound, while Grandpa said aue!

Wow, sorry I'm being negative. [Switching my outlook] I am retiring in May- time to do my world traveling! I'm typing this under my favorite acacia koa tree with a sea view- a small cay is even visible on clear days. I'm eating a homegrown yam- mmm! Also, we started stir frying in a wok, which makes veggies addictive. I relax by repeating fifty oms each morning while focusing on dissolving my ego. Is it working? Aye, of course, better than a gym workout! Grandpa agrees, so... ays have it!

About a week ago, Mr. Smith visited us. He is quite a sui generis gentleman, seemingly an expert in every field! He used to be an ace MiG test pilot. We love to just ask questions to hear amazing answers. First, he explained to us what yaw means. Then he went into tactics he used in a countersuit, sui juris, in response to Dunn County trying to sue over a property boundary issue. Next, he spoke of gem mining, touched on wig making, expounded some benefits of yag laser surgery, clarified cam replacement on Grandpa's truck, provided tips on saving gas, revealed tricks that coy gents might apply to woo their soulmates, showed us karate championship photos with everyone posed in white gis, displayed gay pride parade photos, demonstrated escaping a wolf's maw, ... among other things that I don't recall, I'm sure.

Anyway, I know I owe you a puzzle. It is attached. **Your goal is to name every country I will visit when I retire.**

With Love,
Grandma

---

Partial answers are fine if you are adding at least one stage's answer that was not yet answered.

### Stage 1: Find these 5 non-overlapping paths.

**Tip**: Look off-path.

[Edit: Each number represents a move in the path.]

Paths are horizontal and vertical only.

**Path #1:** 7,1,20,14,3,8,18,19,1,14,2,7,8,4,5,9,2,8,19,17,12,3,2,3,6,3,15,1,6
**Path #2:** 15,14,7,2,6,8,3,11,3,16,9,2,5,7,19,5,1,4,18,3
**Path #3:** 14,9,6,3,4,9,9,1,7,5,1,5,12,17,1,2,15,16,1,12,6
**Path #4:** 10,18,11,10,7,4,14,5
**Path #5:** 16,6,16,14

[image]

---

Text version of the grid above:
EAOTACEBHE
BTPSHFRADT
EHNEMNLTJU
IORBKWRVIO
RDAILSUNST
IFMONEFYAL
JTERHROGIB
CHIUTDSNES
OBNEYXTCIN
ASRTRDESYJ

---

### Stage 2: Apply the Stage 1 clue.

**Tip**: Apply the clue (Horizontal, vertical, and diagonal) to the grid and ignore Grandma's letter (and countries) until stage 3.

---

### Stage 3: Apply the Stage 2 clue.

**Tip**: Think equidistant.

[Edit] Added in a tip above.

[Edit #2] Not equidistant on a map (geographically), but in another way.

[Edit #3] Stage 3's "equidistant" is in alignment with its meaning in the puzzle's theme.

---

### Stage 4: It's research time. (easy, don't worry)

Could be considered a part of stage 3, but I separate them here.

**Tip**: [knowledge](/questions/tagged/knowledge)

Comment: I'm guessing you'd prefer us to work through the puzzle in the order intended, rather than taking a shortcut to the answers if we think we've spotted something significant? Asking for someone who may have been deeply immersed in a similar subject matter of late ;-)

Comment: @Stiv LOL, I wondered if this might be an issue, but I dismissed it. haha. Yeah I'd prefer you work through it in the intended order, but I can't stop you posting the answer by skipping steps. :)

Comment: Haha! I shall respect your puzzle-craft and only answer if I can find the intended way in :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Stage 1

> The puzzle mentions that "paths are horizontal and vertical only" and that "each number represents a move in the path". It would follow that each number dictates, in some way, the relationship between the two letters the path goes between. Specifically, the number is the difference between the numerical equivalents of those two letters. We can then logically and uniquely draw out each of the five paths as so:
>  [image: Stage 1 Grid Image]
>  Reading out the unused letters gives the cluephrase ADJ LTRS NOT ADJ, meaning **ADJACENT LETTERS NOT ADJACENT**.

### Stage 2

> To solve stage 2, you need the cluephrase from stage 1, ADJACENT LETTERS NOT ADJACENT, and the grid of letters. If you cross out every pair of adjacent letters (including diagonal) in the grid that are also adjacent in the alphabet, you get the following grid:
>  [image: Stage 2 Grid Image]
>  Reading out the remaining letters gives EACH THREE LTR WORD IN MY LTR HIDES ONE CNTRY, which means **EACH THREE LETTER WORD IN MY LETTER HIDES ONE COUNTRY**.

### Stage 3

> This stage uses the cluephrase EACH THREE LETTER WORD IN MY LETTER HIDES ONE COUNTRY. In fact, there are 50 three-letter words that can be extracted from the letter. The most interesting aspect of the words is that each of the letters has an odd position in the alphabet. This, combined with the "equidistant" tip, clues that you need to take the letter which is alphabetically in between each pair of letters. You can do this with both pairs of adjacent letters within the trigram to get a list of bigrams. For example, USE becomes TL because T is halfway between U and S, and L is halfway between S and E.

### Stage 4

> Finally, we have to identify a list of countries. As it happens, these bigrams from stage 3 all happen to be ISO 2-letter country codes, meaning each bigram can be transformed into a country name. The resulting bigrams and country names can be seen below:
> `USE    TL  Timor-Leste`
> `WOE    SJ  Svalbard and Jan Mayen`
> `COO    IO  British Indian Ocean Territory`
> `COW    IS  Iceland`
> `MOO    NO  Norway`
> `MAA    GA  Gabon`
> `CAW    BL  Saint Barthélemy`
> `WEE    NE  Niger`
> `MEW    IN  India`
> `AUK    KP  Korea (Democratic People's Republic of)`
> `YAK    MF  Saint Martin (French part)`
> `AYU    MW  Malawi`
> `EMU    IQ  Iraq`
> `SIC    NF  Norfolk Island`
> `SUS    TT  Trinidad and Tobago`
> `EEK    EH  Western Sahara`
> `AUE    KM  Comoros`
> `WOW    SS  South Sudan`
> `MAY    GM  Gambia`
> `KOA    MH  Marshall Islands`
> `SEA    LC  Saint Lucia`
> `CAY    BM  Bermuda`
> `YAM    MG  Madagascar`
> `MMM    MM  Myanmar`
> `WOK    SM  San Marino`
> `OMS    NP  Nepal`
> `EGO    FK  Falkland Islands (Malvinas)`
> `AYE    MO  Macao`
> `GYM    PS  Palestine, State of`
> `AYS    MV  Maldives`
> `AGO    DK  Denmark`
> `SUI    TO  Tonga`
> `ACE    BD  Bangladesh`
> `MIG    KH  Cambodia`
> `ASK    JO  Jordan`
> `YAW    ML  Mali`
> `SUI    TO  Tonga`
> `SUE    TM  Turkmenistan`
> `GEM    FI  Finland`
> `WIG    PH  Philippines`
> `YAG    MD  Moldova, Republic of`
> `CAM    BG  Bulgaria`
> `GAS    DJ  Djibouti`
> `COY    IT  Italy`
> `WOO    SO  Somalia`
> `GIS    HN  Honduras`
> `GAY    DM  Dominica`
> `MAW    GL  Greenland`
> `OWE    SN  Senegal`
> `YOU    TR  Türkiye`

Comment: nice job. you nailed stage 1. ignore Grandma's letter (and the idea of countries) until stage 3. Use the clue you found on the grid again. I added these details into the puzzle.

Comment: V'z gelvat gb qb gur fnzr guvat jvgu gur ahzoref nf V qvq sbe fgntr 1, ohg zbivat orgjrra pryyf nf qrsvarq ol gur pyhr (ba ube/ire/qvnt yvar ohg abg nqwnprag). V'ir nyfb nygreangviryl vagrecergrq gur pyhr nf zrnavat nqwnprag yrggref va fbzr frdhrapr pna'g or nqwnprag (ube/ire/qvnt) naljurer ba gur tevq. Ner rvgure bs gurfr ba gur evtug genpx?

Comment: Never mind, stage 2 solved!

Comment: May I recommend [this](https://www.iata.org/en/publications/directories/code-search/)... :)

Comment: Vg frrzf yvxr HFR JRR RZH NLR LNJ JVT JBB ner gur bayl gevtenzf gung qba'g unir na nffbpvngrq VNGN ybpngvba pbqr. Gur synibegrkg qrsvavgryl zragvbaf svaqvat gur pbhagevrf, fb qb V ernyyl unir gb svaq gur pbhagel anzrf sbe gur bgure 43? V'ir qbar 15-20 fb sne, naq gurl unira'g ernyyl lvryqrq nalguvat, abe unir gur hahfrq jbeqf.

Comment: @SeptaCube very well done! sorry for late response. just woke up for the day. stage 2 looks good, and you found the 50. I will add in a one word clue for stage 3 that I left out on purpose until this point, just in case it might give away too much too soon.

Comment: @stiv good try, but you're on the right general track

Comment: Is this relevant in terms of being "equidistant"?
https://imgur.com/a/vOEVFtG
(using AUK, YAK, EEK, and WOW)

Comment: @SeptaCube I'm not sure I understand, so it is probably not relevant.

Comment: Qb gur gevtenzf npghnyyl unir gb qb jvgu VNGN pbqrf, be abg? Nvecbeg pbqrf qb frrz yvxr gur orfg jnl gb eryngr gevtenzf gb pbhagevrf, bgure guna VFB 3 yrggre pbqrf gurzfryirf.

Comment: Not iata. Not iso3, but those are both very close. Each trigram "hides" a country.

Comment: Is there a final answer I need to find, or just a list of countries? It's slightly unclear since the blurb in the letter seems to suggest that all I need are the countries.

Comment: Yes! Finding the bigrams was stage 3 and finding the countries was stage 4. Great job all around! I finally saw the word "the" in the letter, after checking 10 times and not seeing it. Removing it now! Sorry about that error, even though I'm confident that it did not trip anyone up.